# PROLOG A* search

Tags: prolog

I was trying to implement A* search for KB

```
q:- a.
q:- b,c.
a:- d,e.
a:- c,e,f.
b:- c.
c:- e,f.
e.
f:- e

`Here is my code:
%ARC
arc([H|T],Node,Cost,KB) :- member([H|B],KB), append(B,T,Node),length(B,L), Cost is 1+ L/(L+1).

%heuristic is the length of the node/list which is H
heuristic(Node,H) :- length(Node,H). 

%goal
goal([]). 
%A*
astar(Node,Path,Cost,KB) :- search([[Node, 0, [Node]]], Path, Cost, KB).
%The head of the list New obtained in add-to-fronrier has f-value is 
% no larger than any New's tail, where f(node) = cost(node) + h(node). 

search([[Node, NodeCost, PathtoNode]|_], Path, Cost, _) :- 
    goal(Node), Cost=NodeCost, Path=PathtoNode. 
search([[Node, NodeCost, PathtoNode]|More], Path, Cost, KB):- 
    findall([X, NewCost, [X|PathtoNode]], 
            (arc(Node, X, ArcCost, KB), NewCost is ArcCost+NodeCost), Children), 
    add2frontier(Children, More, New), search(New, Path, Cost, KB). 

%if there are no values to add to frontier=> return frontier

add2frontier([], Frontier, Frontier).
%Take the head of the values. Add it to the frontier. 
%Sort the frontier and recursively call for tail of list 

add2frontier([H|T], Frontier, Result) :- insert_sort(H, Frontier, Sorted),
    add2frontier(T, Sorted, Result). 
                         
%There should be a sorting algorithm for extending the frontier
% insert(X,[], [X]).
% insert(X, [Y|T], [X,Y|T]) :- less-than(X, Y), !.
% insert(X, [Y|T], [Y|NT]) :- insert(X, T, NT). 

insert(X,[Y|T],[Y|NT]):-  insert(X,T,NT).
insert_sort(NewNode, [], [NewNode]).
insert_sort(NewNode, [Head|Tail], [NewNode|[Head|Tail]]) :- lessthan(NewNode,Head).
insert_sort(NewNode, [Head|Tail], [Head|NewTail]) :- lessthan(Head, NewNode), insert(NewNode, Tail, NewTail). 


%less that shows how we move down the tree of lists( nodes)
lessthan([[Node1|_],Cost1],[[Node2|_],Cost2]) :-
    heuristic(Node1,Hvalue1), heuristic(Node2,Hvalue2),
    F1 is Cost1+Hvalue1, F2 is Cost2+Hvalue2,
    F1 =< F2.
```

The problem is that when I ran ii it get just "false" in SWISH Prolog... The program is supposed to give a path and a cost of a path. Could you please tell me why

SWISH Prolog, not returning the expected result

Comment: `goal` only succeeds for `[]`, why? `insert` will not terminate due to some clauses commented out. Check every predicate individually and see if it is working as intended.